# Windows phone 8 GeoFencing using Nokia Maps

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8, geofencing, here-api

How do I go about achieving geofencing on nokia map for windows phone 8. Is it even possible, or should I use other maps api such as Google map? Please advice.

My Requirements: I want to be able to draw a radius on the selected location and when the user move within the radius he will receive a notification.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new **GeoCoordinateWatcher API** deals with this in Windows Phone 8. Geofencing and Geolocation in WP8 formed a major part of the discussion in a recent [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5KnhIFjvT8) on the subject - the slides can be found [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nokia-developer/lumia-app-labs-here-maps-and-location-apis-for-windows-phone). Rather than repeat the code here, I would suggest that you look at the *Track My Position* example which can be found in the [Windows Phone 8 Maps Examples](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/WP8MapsExamples) project on `projects.developer.nokia.com`